# Are people putting bounties on old questions to get a hat?

Tags: discussion, bounty, winterbash

Looking at the featured questions page, there are a pile of really old questions that have new bounties. One even has an accepted answer.

Does this happen every year as an attempt to get all the hats?

*P.S. I like the hats.*

Comment: If you're right, the "hat hunters" are obviously doing it on the cheap. All 9 of the featured questions have only got 50-point bonuses.

Comment: I don't recall if offering bounties was a trigger in previous years, but you will certainly notice hat-related bounties. The tradeoff is bountying away permanent reputation in exchange for a temporary bauble. So I suspect most people will only try for these hats on one site.

Comment: @FumbleFingers There is one 200er!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The long answer to this question is yes. And in response to your other question, also yes. By the way, the short answer is also yes. Both times.

Comment: If there's a hat for "Answered in such an affirmative way that even an SO site bot can feel the positive vibes", I think you've just got one! :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's for hats.

The Gelt hat is for a bounty offered during Hanukkah (December 16 and December 24) and there'll be more offered on Christmas day for the Stockings Hung by the Fire hat.

But not only does the bounty-offerer get a hat, anyone who answers a bounty (and gets an upvote) also gets the Major Award hat!

Yes, there were bounty hats [last](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212999/162511) [year](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/winter-bash-2013-wrap-up/):

> It does not matter on what site you set up a bounty. You get the *Make it rain* hat when you award that bounty to someone.
>
> IG-88 was a less well-known bounty hunter, and the hat that bears his name went to users who tried for a bounty, but didn’t win it.

Hats!

Comment: Speak for yourself. I was (and am) genuinely interested in the question I have placed a bounty on. The question is not mine, it had received very little attention, and I had always considered the OP's answer noteworthy. Some bounties are motivated by "Hats lust" others are a little more serious. (Not that I'm anti-hat, mind you.)